# C# file - output type: console

Tags: c#, monodevelop, console-application, xamarin

I wrote a code, and the line

```
string thing = Console.ReadLine();
```

causes a problem. Xamarin shows me that it did not read in the input this command, so the variable thing becomes null.

I found from other questions and answers here that there are two output types of an application, Window and Console. So, mine probably is not the second one.

But I can't find how to switch to console. I have the latest MonoDevelop and Xamarin, and yet this problem remains. Does anyone know what could help?

Any advice will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What turned out to help was to start a new project, and when Xamarin asks what type, choose C# Console Project. Which seems pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 5):

Rob G Pretty much has it so I'm not sure why you can't see it.  Here's the click-by-click for completeness.

For console output from Xamarin:

Right click the project you have set as startup project, then do:

> Options >> Expand 'Run' >> General >> Check 'Run on external console'

Once this is set, execution will halt on Console.ReadLine();

There is no need to check the 'Pause console output' checkbox.  This simply holds the console open at the end of execution with a 'Press any key to continue...'.

Comment: Thanks, Chris! In this case, the problem was that the application output type was not the 'Console' one, so the Console.ReadLine command could not work well here. On Xamarin, this was decided when the project was being initially created. I'll use your solution next time.

Comment: @LochnessMonster Did you find an easier way than starting over? Is there a setting in the csproj file, perhaps?

Answer (score 2):

Try right clicking on the "options" list item on the menu for your project and making sure Run on external console is marked. It's in the Run -> General tab, I think.

Comment: I still can't see it... Should it be so in Xamarin, or MonoDevelop?

Comment: That's how I remembered it was in MonoDevelop, but if it's not there then my mistake.

Comment: I needed Xamarin, but it's still good to know it works in MonoDevelop :)

Answer (score 0):

Close the project and edit it as text.
Change:

```
<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
```

To:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
```

Then reload the project.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, for some reason, it already was generated with the Exe, so the problem remains.